# Pin/Unpin programs to taskbar in windows 10 powershell script

Tags: shell, powershell, windows-10

Not that great of a scripter but I have a powershell script that pins/unpin taskbar programs. Works fine in windows 7. With our Windows 10 upgrade, the script runs but it does nothing. I have a lot of things to pin/unpin so having a script makes it easier. Here is the sample code:

```
$shell = new-object -com "Shell.Application"  
$folder = $shell.Namespace('C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer')    
$item = $folder.Parsename('iexplore.exe')
$verb = $item.Verbs() | ? {$_.Name -eq 'Pin to Tas&kbar'}
if ($verb) {$verb.DoIt()}

$shell = new-object -com "Shell.Application"  
$folder = $shell.Namespace('C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer')    
$item = $folder.Parsename('iexplore.exe')
$verb = $item.Verbs() | ? {$_.Name -eq 'Unpin from Tas&kbar'}
if ($verb) {$verb.DoIt()}
```

Am I missing anything? Like I said, works well on windows 7. I noticed some of our scripts don't know in windows 10 as well. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Still can't find a solution. I have been searching around and it seems like windows 10 does not allow this? They have a solution for third party apps but that is not possible where I work

Comment: Are you trying to run this locally or pushing it out via Group Policy?

Comment: Seems like a bug in Windows 10: [TechNet - Powershell Pin to Taskbar fails in Windows 10](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7880f228-8491-4005-a82c-152510d8ba03/powershell-pin-to-taskbar-fails-in-windows-10?forum=winserverpowershell). The original [issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1609288/pin-to-taskbar-no-longer-working-in-windows-10) cannot be viewed anymore, because Microsoft Connect has been retired :( Maybe the tool mentioned within [this article](http://www.joseespitia.com/2016/05/13/how-to-programmatically-pin-icons-in-windows-10/) helps

Comment: Maybe you should check if your group policy (from your system admin) if any allows removing them